# Looking for references on campus protests

Tags: reference-request, protests

I am looking for references (books, articles, essays) on campus protests. I am looking for texts that discuss different kinds of campus protests, how they succeed, how they become successful, etc.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment, because it is not exactly what you ask for, but this book: "A Troublemaker's Handbook: How to Fight Back Where You Work - And Win!" would be the reference book if campus was a workplace.

Comment: Any specific countries or time periods?

Comment: @StuartF time periods and countries doesn’t matter.

Comment: Where have you searched already, what search terms did you use, and what did you find?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are basically looking for "how to" references?

Comment: @ohwilleke No. I think question is clear. Protest + students + campus. Any good text (book + article) about that phenomenon?